# split array into unique characters or check if character exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've created 3 buttons with different names, when button A is clicked it appends the value to an array.
for an example

```
<a href="#" class="answer" data-value="Football">Football</a>
```

clicking that will add "Football" to a blank array
I'm creating a basic hangman game and want to know how I would go about either
clicking a letter and checking if that letter exists within the array (i.e clicking f and then checking whether f exists in the word football),
or splitting the array into individual characters (so football becomes f, o, o, t, b, a, l, l) and then clicking a letter will check if that letter exists within the array.

Hopefully that made sense as im quite new to this, so any help would be appreicated

Comment: Do you mean "pressing f and then checking if f exists in football"? At any rate, if the word football is already visible to the user, what kind of Hangman game will this be?

Comment: depence what you are after. with "football".split("") you get an array and with [1,2,3]indexOf(1) you get the position, if it is in the array or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split to create an array of characters, e.g.

```
var guessWord = "Football";
var checkArray = guessWord.split("");
```

check to see if characters is in array:

```
checkArray.indexOf("o")!=-1
```